# How do I move data from local appengine datastore to remote datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I can see how to download the remote datastore to local, and how to upload a CSV to the remote app engine server as outlined here:

[Uploading and Downloading Data](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Uploading_the_Data_to_App_Engine)

But is there a way to export my local data to a CSV that is ready for the remote upload script? Of course I could write a custom exporter, but is there no way to automate this process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is to use the bulkloader.py pointing at your local box:

bulkloader.py --dump --url=http://localhost:8080/remote_api --filename=test.csv --kind=KindHere --app_id=app-id-here

Then you can use the bulkloader.py --restore command to send it to production

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Python Standard Library's [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html).